# Jump to a cell containing today's date in Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to create a function in Google Sheets that will jump to the cell containing today's date.

The following function works if the dates are in one column and formatted as mm/dd/yyyy.

```
function gotoToday() {
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
 var range = sheet.getRange("G:G");
 var values = range.getValues();  
 var day = 24*3600*1000;  
 var today = parseInt((new Date().setHours(0,0,0,0))/day);  
 var ssdate; 
 for (var i=0; i<values.length; i++) {
   try {
     ssdate = values[i][0].getTime()/day;
   }
   catch(e) {
   }
   if (ssdate && Math.floor(ssdate) == today) {
     sheet.setActiveRange(range.offset(i,0,1,1));
     break;
   } } 
}
```

However, the cells containing the dates in my sheet are populated as "=A1+1" etc, and spread across columns as follows:

[image]

How can the function above be edited so it can find and match today's date?

Thank you

UPDATE: I have managed to make the function work across multiple columns. Now I just need to know how to read the date when the cell is populated as =A1+1, A2+1 etc

Comment: Why are you getting values in column G only ?

Comment: That was just me testing the formula to try to understand what wasn't working. If I change it to "B:H" it doesn't work

Comment: I have managed to get this part working now and updated the question

Answer (score 1):

Two things:

1. - Your range is defined as `var range = sheet.getRange("G:G");`
   - This means that your function looks for the date of today only in column G.
   - If you want to extend its functionality over all columns, then you need to define your range e.g. as `var range = sheet.getDataRange();`
   - Consequently, it will not be enough to loop only through rows (`ssdate = values[i][0].getTime()/day;`), but you'll need two nested `for` loops to loop through both rows and columns: `ssdate = values[i][j].getTime()/day;`
2. - Your spreadsheet has certain settings for formatting of dates - depending on your Locale.
   - If you paste into your spreadsheet a date that is formatted differently than your spreadsheet expects - it will not recognize it as a date object and consequently, the method `getTime()` cannot be applied to it.
   - If you want to specify that a cell content is a date - you have to select this cell(s) in the spreadsheet and go to `Format ->Number -> Date`

References:

- [getDataRange()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getdatarange)
- [Locale](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/58515?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en)